# How do I build Python 2.7 with unicode UCS-2 support

Tags: python, python-2.7

I find myself in the unfortunate position of supporting an old application that needs python 2.7.  I pulled down the latest 2.7 release (`wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz`) and installed it, but now I'm getting the dreaded "undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsUTF8String" error from one of the packages in the app.

OK, so back out and run:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs2
make install
python -c "import sys; print('ucs2' if sys.maxunicode == 65535 else 'ucs4')"
```

but I still get `ucs4` for an answer.  Looking at the Makefile the config arguments were passed through:

```
# configure script arguments
CONFIG_ARGS=     '--enable-shared' '--enable-unicode=ucs2'
```

What am I missing?  How do I get UCS-2 supported in my python build?  Running this in an amazonlinux:2018.03 docker container, I don't see any other python installs on it.

Comment: why on earth do you use UCS-2 nowadays? It has completely superseded by UTF-16

Comment: You'll most likely find prebuilt binaries for your system and you shouldn't need to compile Python2 from source. Looks like it's amazon linux, so here you go: https://medium.com/@chrisxu94/how-to-install-python-2-7-pip-and-requirements-txt-on-an-aws-data-pipeline-c292802359dc

Comment: @phuclv As I said, I find myself in the unfortunate position of supporting a very old app, and a module it requires was built using UCS-2.  I don't think I have any way of rebuilding that module to use a different charset, although if there's a way to do that without the sources, I'm listening.

Comment: @tiega I went down the yum path initially, but there were some odd issues installing the old modules, so I decided to try building from source to make sure I knew what was being compiled in.  Which leaves me even more baffled that the configure flags seem to be ignored in the final binary.  I'll have another go at the prebuilt binaries, but would love it if I can solve the question posted.  My gut also says that the yum/pip install will be installed with ucs4 instead of ucs2, bringing me back full circle.

Comment: Grabbing the config vars with `python -c "import sysconfig;print('{}'.format('\n'.join(['{} = {}'.format(v, sysconfig.get_config_var(v)) for v in sorted(sysconfig.get_config_vars(), key=lambda s: s.lower())])))"` gives `CONFIG_ARGS = '...'--enable-unicode=ucs4'...`. So it definitely is ignoring the configure flag altogether

Answer (score 1):

OK, not positive what python is doing with linked libraries, but after fidgeting with this for quite a few hours, it appears that setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH will get me what I want.  I.e.:

```
> ./configure --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs2 --prefix=/fubar/python
...
> make install
...
> export PATH=/fubar/python/bin:$PATH
> python -c "import sys; print('ucs2' if sys.maxunicode == 65535 else 'ucs4')"
ucs4
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/fubar/python/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> python -c "import sys; print('ucs2' if sys.maxunicode == 65535 else 'ucs4')"
ucs2
```

There's probably something obvious in the way all this works, but I haven't had to worry about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a very long time...